# Habilitar .htaccess no Ubuntu 14.10, Apache/2.4.10

Tags: linux, apache, htaccess, ubuntu

Estou tentando habilitar o  .htacces no Ubuntu 14.10,mas vi na hora de configurar que a nova versão do Apache/2.4.10 o modo de configurar 'e diferente das anteriores.

Estou colocando os arquivos no /var/www/

Tentei ja mas nao estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

**apache2ctl -S:**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

**000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory "/var/www/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Tentou `sudo a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart`?

Comment: ja sim mas nao funciona... @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: O que aparece nos logs? `sudo a2enmod rewrite` apresenta algum erro?

Comment: parece tudo certo, a única coisa que percebi é que por padrão a pasta raíz é `/var/www/html/`

Comment: O retorno do sudo a2enmod rewrite:
Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: Como está o conteúdo do seu .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Editar:**

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

**Remover o comentário "#" da linha:**

`AccessFileName .htaccess`

**Reiniciar apache2:**

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: Esta linha estava sem o comentário

Comment: Se você alterar o root da pasta "/var/www/" para outra qualquer (/var/www2 por exemplo) e reiniciar, você recebe erro?

Comment: Quero dizer, separar /var/www/ de **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** com o /var/www/ de **000-default.conf**, surte algum efeito?

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

No terminal entrando em /etc/apache2/sites-available/ acessando o arquivo 000-default acrescentei abaixo de: documentroot /var/www

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
```

Comment: Não use a área de respostas, para pequenos questionamentos/esclarecimentos use os comentários essa parte aqui mais em baixo. O stack overflow funciona diferente da estrutura de um fórum, veja essas diferenças na [tour] (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Me desculpe quando tentei comenta não me foi permitido dava uma mensagem de que era preciso de 50 pontos para fazer o comentário